Two user are not connecting through channel
In my code, two users are not able to connect in a channel together, and an error is occurring: "StreamChatNetworkError(code: 1000, message: Unauthorised, token not defined)".I think my issue lies within my role. I change my role in my code, but it doesn't reflect the change on StreamChat dashboard.
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  /// Create a new instance of [StreamChatClient] passing the apikey obtained
  /// from your project dashboard.
  ///

  final client = StreamChatClient(
    'z7gdxrbmwpmk',
    logLevel: Level.OFF,
  );

  /// Set the current user and connect the websocket. In a production
  /// scenario, this should be done using a backend to generate a user token
  /// using our server SDK.
  ///
  /// Please see the following for more information:
  /// https://getstream.io/chat/docs/ios_user_setup_and_tokens/
  try {
    await client.updateUser(
      User(
        id: '3',
        role: 'admin',
        extraData: const {
          'name': 'test_01',
          'image': 'https://placehold.co/400'
        },
      ),
    );
    await client.connectUser(
        User(
          id: '3',
          role: 'admin',
          extraData: const {
            'name': 'test_01',
            'image': 'https://placehold.co/400'
          },
        ),
        client.devToken('3').rawValue);
  } catch (error) {
    print('There is an error $error');
  }

  final channel = client.channel('messaging', id: '3');

  try {
    await channel.watch();
  } catch (error) {
    print('There is an error $error');
  }
}

